# Checking iF request came from my page jsf

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

I have a servlet that generates an url from cloudfront for a file. It is private file and I want my logged users to be able see them, but also my guests users, they would have a limited amount of requests.  So my servlet generates the url no request but I have no idea how to tell if the request came from a user that was on my site.

Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to answer your question with so little info. It would help to show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a session attribute for logged in users. And then check that attribut in the request for the file. If the attribute exists that means it is a logged in user, if not then the request is coming from a guest.